# My intel xdk project works when i emulate but no when i generate my apk

Tags: android, cordova, intel, intel-xdk

I'm trying to create an app in intel xdk, i'm in the beggining, my code works when i'm emmulating or debugging, but when i generate the apk doesn't work. I just want for a while that when i click in an button my connection type appears down bellow, but this doesn't work in my real device when i install the apk.

I tryied to install in an Nexus 7 with android 5.0.2 and in an Samsung Galaxy Ace with android 2.3.6

here is an video that i made of my project with all permissions and plugins.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-95ybzobAtY&feature=youtu.be

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Blank Hybrid App Project Template</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<style>
    ev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/ */
    @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }                           @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
    @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }                                    @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>


<body>
<h1 class="align-center">A Blank Project Template</h1>
<p class="align-center">
    To use this template as a starter app, start with init-app.js and app.js for your JavaScript code.
    See the README.md file for more details and the comments inside index.html, app.js and init-app.js.
</p>
<br>
<p class="align-center"><input type="button" id="id_btnHello" value="Touch Me"></p>
<p class="align-center"><input type="button" id="bt_test" value="Teste" onclick="conn()"></p>
<p class="align-center" id="desc">testt</p>
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>    
<script src="cordova.js"></script>     
<script src="xhr.js"></script>         

<script src="js/app.js"></script>      
<script src="js/init-app.js"></script> 

<script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript

```
function myEventHandler() {
"use strict" ;

var ua = navigator.userAgent ;
var str ;

if( window.Cordova && dev.isDeviceReady.c_cordova_ready__ ) {
        str = "It worked! Cordova device ready detected at " + dev.isDeviceReady.c_cordova_ready__ + " milliseconds!" ;
}
else if( window.intel && intel.xdk && dev.isDeviceReady.d_xdk_ready______ ) {
        str = "It worked! Intel XDK device ready detected at " + dev.isDeviceReady.d_xdk_ready______ + " milliseconds!" ;
}
else {
    str = "Bad device ready, or none available because we're running in a browser." ;
}
alert(str) ;
}

function conn()
{
    document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML = intel.xdk.device.connection;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can post the APK somewhere so I can test it?  ADB/LogCat should let you know if there is a JS error on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the PERMISSION, that is a very rare requirement. In most cases, the plugins will provide the appropriate permissions required, that is why you are getting the duplicate message in the build log.

Regarding your APK not working, did you select the appropriate Intel XDK plugin? Those get included automatically bt the emulator, regardless of whether or not they have been selected in the plugins settings, but they do not get included in the build unless they have been selected (in the right column of the plugins section on the Projects tab); this is a known deficiency in the Emulate tab (https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/intel-xdk-debug-and-test-overview#EmulateTab).

The API you pointed out requires the intel.xdk.device plugin (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/507858#intel.xdk.device).

I would recommend that you use the Cordova API for what you are doing, some of the functions in that intel.xdk.device API will be deprecated, because they overlap the core Cordova functions. The equivalent Cordova function is https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md, which is part of the "Connection" plugin in the core Cordova list on the left side of the Plugins settings screen.